# Azure Functions host.json Sampling settings not taken into account

Tags: azure-functions, sampling

I'm using InProcess Azure Functions v4 with .NET 6.
I have difficulty enabling sampling for the function.

This is how looks my host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "includedTypes": "Dependency"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As I understand, my Dependencies should be sampled out, but unfortunately this is giving no effect. What is more, I tried using, which is fully ignoring my dependencies, but this is not the behavior I want.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "enableDependencyTracking": false
    }
  }
}
```

For me, it looks `samplingSettings` section itself is malfunctioned. Does everyone facing similar issues?

That are my project config:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="6.0.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Adaptive Sampling will be enabled by default for Azure functions:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request",               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Make sure application insights is enabled/configured in your function app.
- Restart Azure Function after updating sampling settings in  `host.json`.

To Check if the sampling settings is getting reflected,
Go to *Logs* in Application Insights and run the below given query :

```
union dependencies,pageViews,browserTimings,exceptions,traces
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| summarize RetainedPercentage = 100/avg(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h), itemType
```

[image]

If `RetainedPercentage` is less than 100 for any type, then that type of telemetry is being sampled.

***If this doesn't work, refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#brief-summary) to achieve sampling with code.***